# SessionController#create does not behave as expected when repeating login with 2 users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

```
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

  controller.current_user.should be_nil

  post :create, :user => {email: @user.email, password: @user.test_pass}
  flash[:alert].should be_nil
  controller.should(respond_to(:current_user))
  controller.current_user.should_not be_nil

  post :create, :user => {email: @user2.email, password: @user2.test_pass}

  flash[:alert].should be_nil
  controller.should(respond_to(:current_user))
  controller.current_user.should == @user2
```

The last one fails.  It's still @user, not @user2.

**Edit:**

If I do this, is this a fair way to log out the user and clear out the session?

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    if warden.authenticated?(:user)
      sign_out(current_user)
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the flow of devise authentication is quite logic, once you sign-in/sign-up you will be redirected and your session will be started and captured, you will need to sign_out before a new session can be started.

Now I see you are testing the default devise behaviour asking it to sign out the first user when a second is created? well devise does not do this but if this is wanted for your application why not do it using a callback method before_create?

I guess that's the whole idea of Red, Green, Refactor.